# select and upload multiple photos client side

Tags: javascript, image, file, upload

i'm trying to upload images from my computer using this code

```
var filesValues = []

$(photosbtn).click(function() {
    photos.click()

    $(photos).change((e) => {

    const file  = e.target.files[0];

 if (file){

 filesValues.push(file)

console.log(filesValues)
}
```

}}

Now if i select one file the result is one file like this

> 0: File {name:"130492893_1475704719298017_6321765405148113863_n.jpg", lastModified:
> 1607806703000, lastModifiedDate: Sat Dec 12 2020 22:58:23 GMT+0200
> (Eastern European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size:
> 17124, …}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

but if i select one again the result become [the first image ,the second image , the second image ] it repeats the last file like that

> 0: File {name: "130492893_1475704719298017_6321765405148113863_n.jpg",
> lastModified: 1607806703000, lastModifiedDate: Sat Dec 12 2020
> 22:58:23 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time),
> webkitRelativePath: "", size: 17124, …}
>
> 1: File {name: "WhatsApp Image 2020-09-21 at 6.41.36 AM.jpeg", lastModified: 1600663313303,
> lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 21 2020 06:41:53 GMT+0200 (Eastern European
> Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 61490, …}
>
> 2: File {name:"WhatsApp Image 2020-09-21 at 6.41.36 AM.jpeg", lastModified:
> 1600663313303, lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 21 2020 06:41:53 GMT+0200
> (Eastern European Standard Time), webkitRelativeP

and if i select one again ,the last one will be repeated triple and so on .

what is the solution of this , please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer and it is like that

```
var filesValues = []

$(photosbtn).click(function() {
    photos.click()
})

    $(photos).change((e) => {

    const file  = e.target.files[0];

 if (file){

 filesValues.push(file)

console.log(filesValues)
})
```

we shouldn't put the (.change) function inside the (.click) function .

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
filesValues.push ...
```

Try this way:

```
var files = new FormData();
files.append(firstFile);
files.append(secondFile);
```

Comment: The same problem